# MySQL Incorrect datetime value: '12/31/2016 23:59:59' for function str_to_date

Tags: c++, mysql, datetime

Here's the portion of the overall Prepared Statement that I'm having issues with: STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d/%m/%Y %k:%i:%S')

I'm writing in C++ and using a string I'm getting from a data file.

It's inserting 01/01/2017 18:00:10 just fine, but it gets to 12/31/2016 23:59:59 and breaks. I've tried some different combinations but I'm just not getting it.

Comment: @OctoCode Lol, yep, that fixed it. This is what happens when you stare at the same code for 6 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a parsing error, you need to switch days and months you are passing to the function:

```
STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d/%m/%Y %k:%i:%S')
```

from **12**/**31**/2016 23:59:59 to **31**/**12**/2016 23:59:59